# How to implement custom button with three text views in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button

I want to add three textViews in a single button.

I can do it using linearLayout as an XML file and then inflating it to my custom button class but somehow when I set click listener on this type of custom button it won't work.

I desire for a much better option, maybe extending the Android button class and then change it according to my requirement, but unable to inflate my button to my desired views.

Please assist me on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating LinearLayout and setting style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can design your layout with the three textviews as usual. For emulating click, set a `StateListDrawable` as the background of the root container. Put this in any layout (or use `<include>`) and attach a clickListener as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use LinearLayout with 3 textview as its child and set click listener on it. No need to create custom button class. But I do not know exact requirement so need more details for creating custom button class.